# Is it possible to add variable in message box in c?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    char a[20], c[10], d[10];
    int b;
    printf("What is your name: ");
    scanf("%s",&a);
    printf("How old are you: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("Where are you from: ");
    scanf("%s",&d);
    printf("What is your Profession: ");
    scanf("%s",&c);



    MessageBox(0, "My name is" " I am  %s years old. I am from %s. I am a %s. "
              , "Message",1);
    return 0;
}
```

So I am trying to make a program where users ask the question and print the sentences in a message box. is it even possible...?

Comment: Take a look at the `sprintf` and `snprintf` functions.

Comment: The one I linked is actually the same question. TL;DR: it's not possible. You have to build your message prior to it with `sprintf` or equivalent functions.